# MySQL "ALL" statement not working in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am having some issues when trying to use the ALL statement in phpmyadmin ver. 4.5.4.1 (latest).

The ANY statement doesn't seem to cause any issue and all subqueries that make use of ALL actually work when I replace the ALL with an ANY. Here's a sample example:

```
 SELECT * FROM T
 WHERE A >= ALL (
 SELECT T2.A FROM T T2)
```

This query trows the following two error messages:

```
Unrecognized keyword. (near "ALL" at position 50)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 54)
```

And it perfectly works when I switch the ALL with an ANY (but doesn't give the right result).

Is there any known fix? Is it an issue from phpmyadmin's side? Thanks for your time.

Comment: `Try SELECT * FROM T
 WHERE A >= ALL (
 SELECT T2.A FROM T2)`  It looks to me like you're referencing the table "t" again in the second case. Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: They are the same tables, just different instances. T2 is the second, nested instance of T in this query. This query works with ANY, so I don't think the rest of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to me to be a problem with the phpMyAdmin parser library; I've reported it at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12028

Comment: Thanks for taking the initiative to report this issue. Seems to be fixed with this pull request: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/pull/38