# MySQL Unrecognized Keyword near CASE

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having an issue with phpmyadmin 4.6.4 that seems to be identical to these two issues:

- https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12100
- [MySQL "ALL" statement not working in phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490422/mysql-all-statement-not-working-in-phpmyadmin)

According to these, it seems this problem was allegedly fixed in this release, but I'm still receiving the identical list of errors on this code. Here's the code:

**Execute below SQL query in phpmyadmin**

```
select (SELECT name FROM mysql.help_category WHERE help_category_id = 1) as name, 
case when country = "India" then 1 else 0 end as country_flag 
FROM ( select "India" as country ) a;
```

**Getting these errors:**

> An expression was expected. (near "case" at position 91) Unrecognized
>   keyword. (near "case" at position 91) Unrecognized keyword. (near
>   "when" at position 96) Unexpected token. (near "country" at position
>   101) Unexpected token. (near "=" at position 109) Unexpected token.
>   (near "'India'" at position 111) Unrecognized keyword. (near "then" at
>   position 119) Unexpected token. (near "1" at position 124)
>   Unrecognized keyword. (near "else" at position 126) Unexpected token.
>   (near "0" at position 131) Unrecognized keyword. (near "end" at
>   position 133) Unrecognized keyword. (near "as" at position 137)
>   Unexpected token. (near "country_flag" at position 140) An expression
>   was expected. (near "(" at position 159) Unexpected token. (near "("
>   at position 159)

I'm running phpmyadmin 4.6.4 through WAMP64 3.0.6 on WIndows10. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You can avoid the `case` all together and stop worrying what went wrong if you use `IF(country = 'India', 1, 0) as country_flag`

Comment: I switched to using mysql workbench 6.3 and haven't had the problem since. Looks to me like there's still some big issues within library parsing in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 28):

I had encountered same error message with case syntax. You can simply add ( ) around case statement in PhpMyAdmin to execute it.

`select (SELECT name FROM mysql.help_category WHERE help_category_id = 1) as name, (case when country = "India" then 1 else 0 end) as country_flag FROM a;`

Comment: Working fine when using phpmyadmin and putting brackets around the CASE. I need to run update_batch using codeigniter php and have the same issue in CASE, can you suggest an option to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The issue page on GitHub states that support for the `CASE` operator was added in phpMyAdmin 4.6.5. You are running 4.6.4; 4.6.6 and 4.7.0-beta1 are available as of mid-February 2017.

Ubuntu users can upgrade by [adding a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/304827/232993). Users of WampServer can follow [these upgrade instructions](https://john-dugan.com/upgrade-phpmyadmin-wamp/) to extract the [latest official release](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/) to the `C:\wamp\apps` directory and update `phpmyadmin.conf` and `wampmanager.conf`.